# How to change to the Ubuntu desktop using the GUI (not Command Line)?

Tags: gnome, gui, cinnamon

Is there a SUPER SIMPLE way to get the Ubuntu desktop to change to a different desktop using the GUI?  Maybe I'm missing something and just don't trust the command line?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and clarify what exactly you're asking, lest your question be closed as unclear?

Comment: I'll try and add a screenshot of the desktop.  I actually like the desktop that Ubuntu "fails" to better then the normal one.  Is the name of the desktop theme cinnamon?  Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? What is failing? Cinnamon is certainly not part of standard Ubuntu. Please [edit] your question to provide more details about which Ubuntu version you've installed, and such.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try installing cinnamon however what I wanted to do is have the ability to switch between desktops.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: The other question is how to change from cinnamon back to the regular Ubuntu desktop if the normal login settings selector at time of login isn’t available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason **command line** wasn't able to change the login desktop.  I had to use the GUI to update and change to CINNAMON from the default Ubuntu.  Beware however, because you maybe can't switch easily between desktops from Ubuntu (to from) Cinnamon and keyboard shortcuts are not saved!

Here is what the screen shot looks like!  And it works!

[image: Cinnamon Desktop Install]